# How to 'encrypt' information passed along in URL when redirecting in Oracle Apex

Tags: security, redirect, encryption, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have this redirect link in my apex page.

```
f?p=&APP_ID.:2:&APP_SESSION.::NO::P2_ANO:100
```

I want to apply an encryption to my redirect url so that I can hide the values passed to the page items(P2_ANO) . How can I apply encryption to apex redirect url?

Comment: Have you looked at the [DBMS_CRYPTO package](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_crypto.htm#ARPLS65690)? Also what is your requirement here: to prevent people knowing the value, or to prevent people from **changing** the value?

Comment: Can I do both..?

Comment: Yes, you can use DBMS_CRYPTO package to encrypt/decrypt values, and APEX Session State Protection (SSP) to add checksums to URLs that prevent tampering.